# Can a class be abstract and concrete at the same time in java?

Tags: java

Have a doubt :

Can a class be abstract and concrete at the same time in java? i.e if an abstract class has no abstract methods in it, then can it be called a concrete class. Also can we say that any and every class that has no abstract method be called a concrete class?

Comment: Abstract and concrete are antonyms, so they should never be allowed to be the same

Comment: Short answer: no. Even if an abstract class has no abstract methods, it cannot be instantiated. That is the main difference.

Answer (score 5):

The main difference lies in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) where it states:

> An abstract class is a class that is declared abstract—it may or may not include abstract methods. Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but they can be subclassed.

**Instantiation** is the key here.

Comment: But my doubt is regarding whether an abstract class with no abstract methods be called a concrete class?

Comment: Can't instantiate an Abstract class, therefore is not concrete

Comment: @user2580086 No, an abstract class with no abstract methods is not a concrete class.

Answer (score 3):

The answers are "no" and "no". Abstract classes are only those that have been declared with the keyword `abstract`, whether or not they contain abstract methods. A non-abstract class is not allowed to contain abstract methods.